# How to use JaguarDB to store geometric objects

Tags: database, geometry

I found the new feature of Jaguar Database 3.0 is the geometric functions. I am wondering how does it works? What I can do with these objects

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to store geometric object (2d and 3d) and use some basic utility functions afterwards.

1. You can calculate Area, Angle, Dimension etc.
2. You can do Union, Intersection, etc.
3. You can do Rotation or Scaling.

More details available in the [UserManual](http://www.datajaguar.com/doc/JaguarUserManual.pdf)